# How do you set the due date using the D2L REST API?

Tags: desire2learn

I need to be able to create a new assignment with a due date and to be able to update an existing assignment with a due date. I have gone through the documentation on the website but its still not clear to me how we would need to do that. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that, when you use the API route to [create a new dropbox folder on the LMS](https://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/dropbox.html#post--d2l-api-le-(version)-(orgUnitId)-dropbox-folders-) you provide the due date (among other properties) in the JSON structure you provide the call. This is also true of the route to [update a dropbox folder's properties](https://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/dropbox.html#put--d2l-api-le-(version)-(orgUnitId)-dropbox-folders-(folderId)).

Comment: Someone I spoke with about it mentioned that you may be able to set the due date on a deep link. Is this true and something different than doing it on an assignment? If so, how would you set it using the API on a deep link? When I look at the UI for the test bed we are using I can set a start date, due date, and end date. But we need to be able to do the same thing automatically from our tool rather than manually on each deep link using the UI of the platform.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're now asking about creating a link-type Content Topic that links to a dropbox activity -- I believe you can create a link-type Content Topic with a `DueDate` property (see https://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/content.html#Content.ContentObjectData); however, I'm not sure if you can effectively wire it up to the dropbox via the API the way you can via the UI.